# Automatically scraping a dynamic URL that has a date 9 days in the future

Tags: python, datetime, url, dynamic, web-scraping

Every Friday, using crontab, I want to scrape opetable.com for for 1000 pt. reservations for 2 Sunday's in the future. The URL for the page is a result of a submission.

```
html = urlopen('http://www.opentable.com/s/PopRestaurantList?covers=2&currentview=list&datetime=2016-03-06+19%3A00&metroid=15&onlypoptimes=true&personalizer=true&ref=2213&showmap=false&size=100&sort=Popularity')
```

Using urlparse or some other module; and datetime how can I alter the URL to always have the date 9 days from when the scraper runs.

```
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read().decode('utf-8'),"lxml")  
table = bsObj.findAll("div", {"class":"content-section-list infinite-results-list"})  
headlines = table[0].findAll("a", {"class":"rest-row-name rest-name"})  
for headline in headlines:  
    restaurant = (headline.get_text().encode('utf-8'))  
    print(restaurant)  
    print '\n'
```

I have the datetime increment set to 9 days

```
date = datetime.datetime.today()
date += datetime.timedelta(days=9)  
print(date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string formatting and date.strftime to do this:

```
date = datetime.datetime.today()
date += datetime.timedelta(days=9)  
url = 'http://www.opentable.com/s/PopRestaurantList?covers=2&currentview=list&datetime={date}+19%3A00&metroid=15&onlypoptimes=true&personalizer=true&ref=2213&showmap=false&size=100&sort=Popularity'
html = urlopen(url.format(date=date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
```

Comment: When I tried that I get a syntax error after  
    print(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: If you had the print statement after the urlopen, there was a missing paren at the end of the last line in my example code that could have caused the error